# Invalid search string \{

Tags: neovim, nvchad

I am new to Neovim regex and nothing seems to be working. \b is intepreted litterally and `\{` acts like if there's no `\`.
However `\`. works. What may be wrong? I have noticed that in my browser \ gets repaced by a character described as W bar. I think this happens since I installed nerd fonts. It should be inconsequential but unsure. I am working on a fresh NVChad install even though I am unsure this setup can affect the matter.

Comment: Could you provide us an example of pattern you are trying and explaining what you want to match? That would very helpful to us to guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some remarks that could help you.

The words boundaries are matched in Neovim using `\<` and `\>` (not using `\b` like in VisualStudio Code)

To match `{` you can simply use `{`

The `\{` has a special meaning to specify quantifiers.

`\d\{3}` match `421` but do not match `42`

More information: `:help pattern`

Comment: Reference: `:help pattern`